# How do I reformat a javascript cdata string into array?

Tags: javascript, arrays, string, split, epoch

Still learning... sorry if this doesn't make sense or sounds stupid :P

I have 2 variables "timestamps" and "clicks" and a string of numbers:

```
{
  "timestamps":[
    1362096000000,1362355200000,1362441600000,1362528000000
  ],
  "clicks":[
    [
      1,2,3,4
    ]
};
```

What would be the easiest way to reformat the string and output into an array like this:

```
[1362096000000,1],
[1362355200000,2],
[1362441600000,3],
[1362528000000,4],
```

Comment: Can you post your code so far and a demo to reproduce the issue you have?

Comment: I assume you have either one too many opening brackets on your "clicks" property or forgot the closing bracket and that it's all a typo.

Comment: Robbert is correct - there's one too many left-brackets on clicks (or one two few right brackets). Also, I can only see the "timestamps" and "clicks" variables, but not the string of numbers. Can you please explain further how you want your string formatted in the output?

Comment: Don't have code to do it yet, just the data sets, was trying to figure out the easiest way to do it and was reading about sorting arrays and string.split

Answer (score 2):

Just based on the limited information you've given us, and assuming the constraints of both `timestamps` and `clicks` always being the same length of arrays, and that you want the output to be an array this will create the new desired format.

```
var output = []; 

for (var i = 0, l = obj.timestamps.length; i < l; i++) { 
    output.push([obj.timestamps[i], obj.clicks[i]]);
}

/*output is now [
   [1362096000000,1],
   [1362355200000,2],
   [1362441600000,3],
   [1362528000000,4]
]*/
```

Comment: Thanks Robert!! But how would I output? When I run on page, it's blank.

Comment: This is just Javascript, so it's not going to output anything on a page by default. You'll need to clarify on how you want it to output.

Comment: To output in the <body> or as a json file.

Comment: The code above will give you a variable named `output`, do with it what you will. If you want it in a JSON file, look up `JSON.stringify` etc.